# Applying theorem to disprove uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I recently read this theorem in real analysis:(Actually a corollary to a theorem)

{$f_m$} is a sequence of continuous functions defined on $D$ such that $f_m$$\to$$f$ uniformly on $D$ then for every sequence {$x_m$} in $D$ satisfying $x_m$$\to$$x$ then $f_m(x)$$\to$$f(x)$.

please correct me if I wrote this wrong. The doubt is that I am unable to use it in a problem:
$$f_m(x)=\dfrac{mx}{1+mx}\qquad       x\in[0,1].$$
I want to prove that this is not uniformly convergent, but I am not able to understand what is $x_m$. How does it depend on $m$? Does it even depend on $m$? 
If yes then how to prove that $f_m(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ when $x_m$ tends to $x$(to show that it is not uniformly convergent).(also, is there $x_m$ or $x$ inside $f_m(\cdot)$ . Basically, how to approach this problem, please explain stepwise because I need to get the feeling of this theorem.

Comment: Are you sure the original statement is correct?  I suspect that it should be about a sequence {$x_n$} where $x_n\to x$ and $f_m(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Comment: I am not really sure about it. You might be right here. I'll change it when someone else points it out too.Thanks!

Comment: @herbsteinberg I believe that n=m, because if they are not, then finding $f_m(x_n)$ will be vague since it will be a sequence of functions and so we will have to vary both $n$ and then $m$ to find out what $f_m(x_n)$ converges to. Correct me if i am wrong. Also take a look at the comment by Yadati.

Comment: Since I am not familiar with this theorem, the comment by Yadati may be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to show $f$ is not uniformly convergent.
$$f_m=\begin{cases}0 &x=0\\\dfrac{mx}{1+mx} &x\neq0\end{cases}$$ $\:$For $x\neq0\:$   $f_m(x)=\dfrac{mx}{1+mx}=\dfrac{x}{\frac1m+x}$. $\:$ Now if $m\to\infty\implies f_m(x)\to1$.

So $$f_m\to\begin{cases}0 &x=0\\1 &x\neq0\end{cases}=f$$

and $f$ is clearly not continuous. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

$\rule{17cm}{1pt}$

$0\neq x_m=\dfrac1m\to0\implies\:\forall\:m\quad f_m(x_m)=\dfrac12\not\to f(0)=0$. So the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Your explanation is right, but I specifically want to use the above corollary to prove it.

Comment: Consider $x_n=\frac1n$

Comment: According to you Is the mistake pointed out above by herb correct?

Comment: Yes the theorem should be " Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, $f_n$ are continuous,  and $x_n\rightarrow x$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n) =f(x) $"

Comment: @Cosmic: $f_m(x_m)=\dfrac{m\cdot\frac1m}{1+m\cdot\frac1m}=\dfrac12$